# My Sql PIVOT Query Is Not Working As Intended

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016

I'm using the following SQL query to return a table with 4 columns `Year`, `Month`, `Quantity Sold`, `Stock_Code`,

```
SELECT yr,  mon, sum(Quantity) as Quantity, STOCK_CODE
FROM [All Stock Purchased]
group by yr, mon, stock_code
order by yr, mon, stock_code
```

This is an example of some of the data BUT I have about 3000 Stock_Codes and approx 40 x yr/mon combinations.

```
yr    mon  Quantity  STOCK_CODE
2015  4    42        100105
2015  4    220       100135
2015  4    1         100237
2015  4    2         100252
2015  4    1         100277
```

I want to pivot this into a table which has a row for each SKU and columns for every Year/Month combination.

I have never used Pivot before so have done some research and have created a SQL query that I believe should work.

```
select * from
(SELECT yr, 
mon, Quantity,
STOCK_CODE
FROM           [All Stock Purchased]) AS BaseData
pivot (
sum(Quantity)
For Stock_Code
in ([4 2015],[5 2015] ...........
) as PivotTable
```

This query returns a table with Yr as col1, Mon as col2 and then 4 2015 etc as subsequent columns. Whereas I want col1 to be Stock_Code and col2 to show the quantity of that stock code sold in 4 2015.

Would really like to understand what is wrong with my code above please.

Comment: Please provide sample data with desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using pivoting.

```
SELECT  P.`STOCK_CODE`,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN P.`yr`=2015 AND P.`mon` = '1' 
            THEN P.`Quantity` 
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS '1 2015',
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN P.`yr`=2015 AND P.`mon` = '2' 
            THEN P.`Quantity` 
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS '2 2015',
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN P.`yr`=2015 AND P.`mon` = '3' 
            THEN P.`Quantity` 
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS '3 2015',
FROM    [All Stock Purchased] P
GROUP BY P.`STOCK_CODE`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. What is P.'company_name' doing? Why the P?

Comment: P.company_name has been corrected as p.STOCK_CODE. P was used as the table alias. For this example table alias doesn't add much sense.just a sql habbit. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following query using dynamic `PIVOT` should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Yr INT,Mnt INT,Quantity INT, Stock_Code INT)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
(2015,4,42,100105),
(2015,4,100,100105),
(2015,5,220,100135),
(2015,4,1,100237),
(2015,4,2,100252),
(2015,7,1,100277)

DECLARE @pvt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SET @pvt = STUFF(
  (SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Mnt) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Yr)) FROM #temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,N'');

EXEC (N'
SELECT pvt.* FROM (
    SELECT Stock_Code
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Mnt) +'' ''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Yr) AS [Tag]
        ,Quantity
    FROM #temp )a
    PIVOT (SUM(Quantity) FOR [Tag] IN ('+@pvt+')) pvt');
```

Result is as below,

```
Stock_Code  4 2015  5 2015  7 2015
100105      142     NULL    NULL
100135      NULL    220     NULL
100237      1       NULL    NULL
100252      2       NULL    NULL
100277      NULL    NULL    1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I am reading this correctly then the first  INSERT INTO would need to list all combinations of Year, Month and Stock_Code?  I have about 3000 Stock_Codes and 50 combinations of Year/Month.

Comment: `Insert Into...` is used to create a demo table, you need to create all combination of Year/Month using `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Mnt) +'' ''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Yr)` within the query